# Having trouble understanding .join(map(re.escape, example))

Tags: python, sorting, escaping

I'm having trouble understanding what .join(map(re.escape, example))

I tried reading the documentations and example codes but to no avail

```
operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/', '**']
print ('|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(operators, reverse=True)))

# output will be \/|\-|\+|\*\*|\*
```

so I am not sure if my understanding is correct but what I think this line of code is doing is

1) the array of special characters will be sorted in reverse order

2) use the map function to map the elements in the array to the escape function so I can print out the special characters as they are

3) I join then using the '|'

but the output is very different from what my understanding is telling me. Would be great if someone can explain to me why the output is what it is ? Thanks a whole lot in advance.

Comment: How does the output differ from your understanding? Seems like you have described exactly what's happening here.

Comment: if using my understanding shouldn't the output be *\\*\ | / | * | - | + instead ?

Comment: `sorted(operators, reverse=True)` is a very weird thing to do (reverse Unicode order, which achieves the necessary effect of putting `**` before `*`, but… yeah). Did you mean `reversed(operators)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is nothing weird in `reverse=True` as *Ry-* commented.
The only change introduced by it is that the sort is in **descending**
order. Compare both variants:

- `sorted(operators)` results in `['*', '**', '+', '-', '/']` (normal (ascending) sort),
- `sorted(operators, reverse=True)` results in `['/', '-', '+', '**', '*']` (descending sort).

Then `map(re.escape, ...)` applies `re.escape` to each element of the list.

It happend that each char in every element is a special regex char, so each of them is
prepended with a backslash, and hence the result is: `['\/', '\-', '\+', '\*\*', '\*']`.

Then `join` (as the name indicates), joins these strings, inserting a `|` between them.

So the result is just as you wrote (*output will be ...*).

Additional remarks:

1. I see that you create here a regex pattern with
   alternatives. So, at least in this case, the order of alternatives
   is not important and you can omit *reverse=True*.
2. Your comment that the expected result should be `*\*\ | / | * | - | +`
   indicates that you neither know which chars are special regex chars
   nor how `re.escape` works.
   Search the Web for instructions about regex and read them.

Comment: *“I see that you create here a regex pattern with alternatives. So, at least in this case, the order of alternatives is not important and you can omit reverse=True.”* Congratulations, you figured out why I said it was weird. But no, you can’t necessarily omit `reverse=True` if you need to guarantee the preference of `\*\*` over `\*`. For that, you would maybe use `reversed` without sorting, hm?

Comment: *Ry-*, you are right. Another choice is to set the proper order on your own (first `**` then `*` and then all remaining in any order) and remove *sorted* whatsoever.